# How to append my miliseconds to my image name before saving?

Tags: php, image, file, save

I use an MVC. This is my function in my model:

```
public function saveImagenPerfil($data){
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
    $table = $this->getTable();

    $milliseconds = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
    $foto = JRequest::getVar('imagen', null, 'files', 'array'); 
    $data['imagen'] = $foto['name'];

    $table->load($data['cid'][0]);

    if ($data['imagen']!=""){
        $this->saveImagen($data['cid'][0], $foto);
        $table->set('imagen' , $data['imagen']);
    }

    if (!$table->check() or !$table->store()){  
        return 1; // no se puede guardar en base de datos
    }
}
```

I need to add `$milliseconds` in front of the image name before it saves in the folder and database. How can I do this?

If you need more information I will try to provide as much as possible.

This is what `$foto` brings back

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "IMG_2233.JPG" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(26) "/var/zpanel/temp/phpGB5kUE" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(2737252) }
```

Comment: `$milliseconds . $foto['name']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to overwrite the filename before passing the whole `$foto` array to your save function:

(**note:** this answer is posted as request by the OP [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/15347638#15347638)):

```
public function saveImagenPerfil($data){
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
    $table = $this->getTable();

    $milliseconds = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
    $foto = JRequest::getVar('imagen', null, 'files', 'array'); 
    $data['imagen'] = $foto['name'];

    $table->load($data['cid'][0]);

    if ($data['imagen']!=""){
        $foto['name'] = $milliseconds . $foto['name'];
        $this->saveImagen($data['cid'][0], $foto);
        $table->set('imagen' , $data['imagen']);
    }

    if (!$table->check() or !$table->store()){  
        return 1; // no se puede guardar en base de datos
    }
}
```